# emacs: recognising the shebang line

Tags: emacs

How can I configure Emacs to recognise certain she-bang lines?

it recognises the shebang line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

but not the shebang line of

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby1.9
```

I figure there must be an alist somewhere with the list of scripting languages called by /usr/bin/env  and the mode, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is controlled by [`interpreter-mode-alist`](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Choosing-Modes.html#Choosing-Modes). In my Emacs (23.2.1 on Debian), there's an entry for `ruby1.9` out of the box. I guess you have an older version; you can add this to your `.emacs`:

```
(add-to-list 'interpreter-mode-alist
             '("ruby1.9" . ruby-mode))
```